# How to remove records when ID has at least one related measure = 0

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

Essentially, with reference to the table, I want to exclude all matching IDs in this case `C123` because it has at least one of the `UsedResources = 0`.

Any help or advice would be very appreciated here.

| PersonalID | ID_Holder | AssigmentTags | UsedResources |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C123 | Kratos | AS001 | 0 |
| C123 | Kratos | AS999 | 15 |
| C123 | Kratos | AS542 | 20 |
| P567 | Zesus | AS874 | 25 |
| P567 | Zesus | AS123 | 10 |
| P567 | Zesus | AS983 | 5 |

Comment: remove them from the data/script or chart/table?

Comment: I'd very much like solutions both in the script and at the front end. If not too much to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Script**

You can flag these records and the use the flag to filter them out in the UI

```
RawData:
Load * Inline [
PersonalID, ID_Holder, AssigmentTags, UsedResources
C123      , Kratos   , AS001        , 0
C123      , Kratos   , AS999        , 15
C123      , Kratos   , AS542        , 20
P567      , Zesus    , AS874        , 25
P567      , Zesus    , AS123        , 10
P567      , Zesus    , AS983        , 5
];

join

Load
  PersonalID,
  if(MinUsedResources > 0, 1, 0) as HasNonZeroResources
;  
Load
distinct
  PersonalID,
  min(UsedResources) as MinUsedResources
Resident
  RawData
Group By
    PersonalID
;
```

Once the app is reloaded then `HasNonZeroResources` field can be used in the expressions:

With Set analysis:

```
count( {< HasNonZeroResources = {1} >} AssigmentTags)
```

Without Set analysis:

```
// not sure how effective is this
count( AssigmentTags ) * HasNonZeroResources
```

**Expression**

One way is to only include `PersonalID` for which the minimum value for `UsedResources` is

```
count( {< PersonalID = {"=min(UsedResources) > 0"} >}  AssigmentTags)
```